# Angular Service with Azure Cosmos

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-cosmosdb

I am really new to Angular. I am trying to create a service which i want to consume in my angular component. While doing so i am getting below error.

Below is my code which i am writing

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { CosmosClient } from '@azure/cosmos';
import {Observable,of} from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  
  databaseId='dbName';
  containerId='Container Name';
  constructor() { }

  public async getProjects():Promise<Observable<any>>{
    const endpoint = "https://AAAA.documents.azure.com:443/";
    const key = "==";
    const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });
    const database = client.database(this.databaseId);
    const container = database.container(this.containerId);

    const querySpec = {query: "SELECT * from c where c.Category=\"Details\""};
    const { resources:items } = await container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();
    return of(items);
  }
  
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

[image: Error Picture]

Comment: Please edit your question to show your actual error. You only showed a code block, and it's not obvious what error you're getting, or where the error is happening in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I have added picture of my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an exception to every rule, but the use cases for connecting to a DB directly from a web browser are pretty close to zero. By doing so, you lose all fine grained control over what a user can do in your database and the only way to revoke access is to rotate your keys. You may not currently have anything in your database that is sensitive, but it is still considered bad practice.

For this reason, the CosmosDB library is compatible with NodeJS as a server-side framework. Whether or not it works with front end frameworks like Angular or React are incidental. There are some large changes in how Angular compiles projects in version 9, and it looks like the Cosmos client is not compatible with the new Ivy compiler.

You do have a couple options here.

1. *(recommended)* Use an API layer between your database and your front end. You can use Node to keep it within Javascript. If you are running on Azure, there are services like Azure Functions that can make this even easier to implement securely, or you can run it from the same App Service, VM, or whatever hosting solution you are using.
2. [Disable](https://angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility) the new Ivy compiler.You can do this by adding `aot: false` in your angular.json

Comment: you are correct, I do have a Node service layer in between. but just wanted to check if this is possible or not.

Comment: Awesome. :) You could make it work if you really wanted, just not a good idea.

Comment: my only worry is if I go ahead with node services then i might have to buy a container in azure and pay for it ;) and my app is not that big. so porting this into good old .net platform  (.net core application) which allows APIs + Angular SPA in one app. (at least that is what my limited understanding) . Hopefully will save bucks...

Comment: There are several ways to host websites in Azure of course, but if you don't have a large amount of traffic, hosting the API as a Function app might be something to look at. Unlike the free tier in App Services, the Functions consumption plan doesn't have any special restrictions, and there is a decently large free grant before the billing on that kicks in.

Comment: You can use Functions proxies to host the Angular portion in Storage while still putting the *.azurewebsites.net or your custom domain in front of it. The storage cost isn't free, but Functions + Storage is very likely to be less expensive than an App Service plan or a VM.

Comment: I really wish, if there is some resources who can give such amazing advices. This is awesome... I will definitely consider this....